# Can not include <linux/thread_info.h> in c program

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm writing C program to get process `current` in Linux. But I can't include `<linux/thread_info>`: "NO SUCH FILE OR DIRECTORY". I met the same problem when I include some thing as `<asm/thread_info.h>` or `<threads.h>`. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: i find library in /usr/include but i cann't find them

Comment: If by "C program" you mean **user-space** program, then you definitely cannot include the header file `linux/thread_info.h`, because it is intended for **kernel code** only. In any case, we need more information about your program and the way how do you compile it. Ideally, we want [mcve].

Comment: i write get_process.c by nano and compile my program by gcc. it run on user-space. i want to get infomation of current process. if my way is wrong, can you direct me to do this

Comment: You cannot access from the user space those objects (structures), which are intended only for the kernel. If you want to know a specific attribute of the current process, it could be syscalls, files in special filesystems or utilities which can help you.

Comment: i am reading the linux kernel development and i want to code follow it and forgot completely that it is code in kernel space. thank you so much Tsyvarev!

Comment: You can find a lot of information about the current process by reading files in `/proc/self`.

Comment: Thank void. i saw it. in additon, when i create my module, i can include the header file (linux/thread_info.h) and run in kernel space, right?

Comment: Just including the kernel header file will not make your program run in the kernel space. The code needs to be compiled as a [loadable kernel module](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/x73.html). Then it will be loaded once on startup and it will be difficult to run it on demand from the command line.

Comment: It would also help if the answer was reformulated in the way "how do I achieve this?" instead of "what is wrong with this approach?". What information about the process do you need to obtain?